# How could I create a one click hyperlink for websites like https://www.integral-calculator.com/ that automatically pastes into the Javascript box?

Tags: javascript, python, hyperlink, mathjax

[My web app](https://nsc9.github.io/) generates Calculus I problems in Latex and non-Latex form.

I use these two websites to check my answers:

https://www.derivative-calculator.net/

https://www.integral-calculator.com/

E.g., I copy/paste the non-Latex form of the math problem `log(v)/v**4` and put it into the Integral calculator website to understand the gaps in my knowledge that is stopping me from solving the problem independently on my own by hand writing/hand solving.

I am writing this post because I want to improve my web app and reduce the steps it takes for the user to check their answers to one of these calculators. Right now, the user has to copy the equation, click the website link, then paste the equation into the website Javascript box, and finally click "Go" to be able to see suggested steps to solve the problem.

I want to take some string the represents my equation (e.g. `log(v)/v**4`) and turn it into a one click hyperlink like https://www.integral-calculator.com/log(v)/v**4

A link such as this does not work, presumably because the website is using a JavaScript or MathJax feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in that, as these websites do not use URL parameters, you will not be able to generate a URL from within your app that auto-populates the required fields. Additionally, these websites do not appear to use any sort of publicly accessible API (they take form data and process the results on the server side).

My suggestion would be to use an existing public API to check results within your app. I believe [Wolfram Alpha](https://products.wolframalpha.com/api) allows up to 2000 API calls per month for free.